# How to place admob banner at bottom of screen in iOS retina and non retina

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova

I've built a phonegap app and want to add an Admob banner to it. I have the banner working at the bottom of the screen in iOS6 simulator but when I test it on a retina device the banner will be way off of the bottom like it's still trying to size the screen for a non retina display. Here is my current code in viewDidLoad:

```
// Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

// Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                             origin:origin];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by moving the above code from `viewDidLoad` to `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this,

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to count for NavigationBar and Status Bar:

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height -
                             self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height -
                             20 /* status bar */);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, so it may already be working, but using the non-origin init and resetting the origin afterwards seems to work:

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

// Omitted: set up ad id, etc

CGRect frame = bannerView_.frame;
frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - frame.size.height;
bannerView_.frame = frame;

[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```